# Can't get ImageMagick -fft to execute in Command Prompt

Tags: windows-7, imagemagick

I downloaded ImageMagick (Windows 7 64-bit) and FFTW, and I can do simple commands but I can't use the `-fft` option.

Commands are from the ImageMagickv6 examples. None of the examples with `-fft` work. The status of various commands is as follows:

```
convert -size 128x128 xc:gold constant.png                (WORKS)

convert constant.png -fft +delete constant_magnitude.png  (DOES NOT)
```

I get these messages:

```
convert.exe: delegate library not built-i"constant.png" (FFTW) @ warning/fourier.c/ForwardFourierTransformImage/982
convert.exe: no images defined 'constant_magnitude.png @error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the output of this command:

```
convert -version
```

In my case, I get:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64 2014-12-06 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib gvc \
                      jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo \
                      png ps rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

This means, in ***my*** installation, the `fftw` *delegate* is available. (The first ImageMagick version, where this was available is v6.5.4-3.)

For ImageMagick, a 'delegate' is an external program or an internal add-on module, which can take care of certain tasks. `fftw` is there for 'fast fourier transforms'.

If your command output of `convert -version` does not list `fftw`, you are out of luck. You need to install a different version which includes it.

---

### Update

It seems that in the pre-compiled binaries for Windows, there is no support for the `fftw` delegate. FFT is implemented via an external library, which is under the GPL license. This was the reason for IM developers not being able to include it by default.

It seems you'll have to build IM on Windows on your own from sources to get FFT support there.